# How to navigate back and forth between two power apps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I want to use the navigate function on power apps to jump from one app to another, then be able to take the user back to the original app. Currently I have it set up so the user can get from the first app to the second, but there's no way to navigate them back. If possible, I'd also like for the app to store any inputs they may have already made.

Answer (score 1):

Check out deep linking.

- MSFT Deep linking documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/how-to/deep-linking
- Here is a demo video from Shane Young: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5Pi5P2YKds